# Firefox extension development : Get URL of new tab

Tags: firefox-addon

How can I get the URl of the next tab on Firefox? I am using this now:

```
//The browser object points to the new tab which I capture using the
//'TabOpen' Event
var browser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(event.target);

//From where can I get the URL of this new tab ? Also, how to I get
//the Title of this new Tab
```

Answer (score 14):

First [search google for "getBrowserForTab"](http://www.google.com/search?q=getBrowserForTab&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) to see what kind of object it returns. You'll see a page with examples as the first hit, and the [reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL:Method:getBrowserForTab) as the second hit. The latter is what we're looking for. It says:

> [getBrowserForTab( tab )] Returns a [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL%3abrowser) for the specified tab element.

Follow the link for [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL%3abrowser) to see what properties and methods this object has.

You'll see it has a [contentTitle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL%3abrowser#p-contentTitle) property ("This read-only property contains the title of the document object in the browser."), which answers the second part of your question.

Similarly you see it has a [currentURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL%3abrowser#p-currentURI) property which returns "the currently loaded URL". The returned object is an `nsIURI`, to get its string representation you need to use `currentURI.spec`, as described in the [nsIURI documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIURI).

So to sum up:

```
var title = browser.contentTitle; // returns the title of the currently loaded page
var url = browser.currentURI.spec; // returns the currently loaded URL as string
```

You could also just get the `window`/`document` objects of the content page via `browser.contentWindow`/`browser.contentDocument` and get the title/URL (and other things) using the APIs you would use in a regular web page.