# Firefox addon / javascript: get url from bar

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I followed the example code from the addon dev site have successfully put a button onto FF :)
now i want to make that button do something interesting so I thought I would run an alert with the address that is currently in the bar... but this does not work:

```
CustomButton = {

1: function () {
  alert("Just testing 1"+document.location.href);
  },

}
```

except for the `+document.location.href` it's the exact demo code I got from the dev site...

Answer (score 3):

You should note that in extension developing, document and window variables refers to the Host Browser not the browser that contains the web site.
you should use

> gBrowser.selectedTab

for getting current tab and then using

> currentURI.host

for getting URL host
also note that selectedTab returns a tab variable then you should get the window of that tab.
then the whole code will be:

> gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(gBrowser.selectedTab).currentURI.host

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get the location of current document or the string that is in the location bar?

For location of current document

```
content.location.href
```

For the string in location bar

```
document.getElementById("urlbar").value
```

or

```
gURLBar.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Those work for me, what context are you using it/how are you calling the function?

```
 > document.location.href
 < "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352035/firefox-addon-javascript-get-url-from-bar"
```

You can also use `window.location.href`

```
 > window.location.href
 < "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352035/firefox-addon-javascript-get-url-from-bar"
```

Comment: When I try that I get this in my alert: 
Just testing 1chrome://browser/content/browser.xul

Comment: If I had to guess it sounds like you're executing within the context of the chrome of the window (menu's, buttons etc) rather than the actual page. You may want to look at http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/

Comment: Ok, got it working by doing this:
var urlbar = window.content.location.href;

  alert("Just testing 1"+urlbar);
Thanks for replying though!

Answer (score 1):

Try `alert("The current page URL is " + browser.currentURI.spec)` and see how that goes for you.

See also:

[Firefox extension development : Get URL of new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226635/firefox-extension-development-get-url-of-new-tab) and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIURI

Answer (score 0):

Took a while to figure it all out:

```
gBrowser.currentURI.spec;
```

is how you do it.

Here's some code you may find useful

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (e) {

  var href = gBrowser.currentURI.spec;

  if ( href.match(/website.com/) ) {

    var contentDoc = content.document;
    // Do some stuff to the current website.com's DOM

  }

}, true);
```