# Firefox Sidebar Getting Tab URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to make a quick Firefox sidebar addon, using [Simple Sidebar](https://github.com/kyoshino/simple-sidebar) as the base.

I'm getting the current tab URL, and I want it to change in the sidebar automatically, so that when you change tab or URL the sidebar shows the corresponding page.

I have been trying to alter this line (line 56 in bootstrap.js):

```
bc.setAttribute('sidebarurl', URL HERE);
```

I have tried the `mainWindow.content.location.href`, `window.location.href`, `gBrowser.contentWindow.location.href` attributes, and the best I can do is to make the browser show a smaller browser with a blank tab inside the sidebar.

I can't work out what I'm missing, do I need to include something else?

Comment: Have you tried `browser.currentURI.spec` or `gBrowser.currentURI.spec` from  [Firefox extension development : Get URL of new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226635/firefox-extension-development-get-url-of-new-tab) and [Sidebar to display the page URL](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1047805).

Answer (score 0):

The `window` variable is already there, passed as an argument of `add_elements`. This window `refers` to XUL window.

Since in bootstrapped extensions, global variables such as `gBrowser` are not available, we will use `window` to find `tabbrowser` and then from `tabbrowser`, find the [current URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/XUL/tabbrowser#p-currentURI):

```
// find the tabbrowser element of window 
var gBrowser = window.document.getElementById("content");
bc.setAttribute('sidebarurl', gBrowser.currentURI.spec);
```

Comment: Please add some relevant reasoning for why the O.P. should "Use this code"; without more explanation, the answer may end up being flagged for deletion.